# Remove quotes from regex result

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code:

```
$source = '<value_date spot_date="2014-11-24" tenor="TODAY">2014-11-20</value_date>';

#get the tenor
$source=~  /tenor=\s*(.*?)\s*>/;

print $1;
```

This prints a result of "TODAY" (double quotes are part of the result). I would like to remove the double quotes from the start and end. eg, I would like a result of TODAY. Can this be done in the regular expression to extract the tenor? Alternatively, what's the next best way to remove the first and last characters, or to replace " with a whitespace?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I should mention, I have no modules to do any xml parsing, so please don't give me any grief over that :)

Comment: `use XML::Simple; print XMLin($source)->{tenor};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the pattern so that `"`s are not to be part of the capturing group:

```
$source =~ /tenor="(.*?)">/;
```